# I want to use IN operator while getting the list of items from DynamoDB

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a set of domains in variable `domains_hash`  and I want to get all the items from dynamo table which has domain from `domains_hash` .

The column `domain` in the table is a partition key.

This is how I have tried to do it so far -

```
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

domains_hash =('196af8b5fca2fa43e8f328d7bd996eafc2d799c1b90233a84d43a5c8cd52ac97',
 'f4af8a416f59f0829e39006e59a3698a3580d310ae2617dcc418b33a90cc9f01',
 '3bf08cfb1b1a363c04ae2ce1c1177641ffb9ca09bc835faff47c025d5379ae6e',
 '6dd22c3e88531abea2dec8403a2a1d9bc23376470c4bc2b2145fd03deef270bb',
 'a402e656cf14b4794fd3762074ad4689cd086efa7c377ae19d68c4d38cee41f3',
 '6d9d3804f2fa1e876533cb3131b1c49414dfbcd710b4710922426244971145ca',
 'f92c9f9a1799251fec6d397a22271183b01625c279b4af324cb49056a62633f4')


try:

    res = endpoint_users.query(
        ConditionExpression="domain IN :dh",
        ExpressionAttributeValues={':dh': domains_hash},
        ScanIndexForward=False,
    )
except ClientError as e:
    raise DopeException
```

But I am getting this error -

```
ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "ConditionExpression", must be one of: TableName, IndexName, Select, AttributesToGet, Limit, ConsistentRead, KeyConditions, QueryFilter, ConditionalOperator, ScanIndexForward, ExclusiveStartKey, ReturnConsumedCapacity, ProjectionExpression, FilterExpression, KeyConditionExpression, ExpressionAttributeNames, ExpressionAttributeValues
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first you need [KeyConditionExpression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) for your query and not ConditionExpression. However IN operation isn't supported in queries. Your options are:

- Do a scan
- Run multiple queries matching a single domain id
- Use OR in your expression to request more than one domains